# How can I add a generated source folder to my source path in Gradle and IntelliJ?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle, thrift

I use thrift and it generates some source java files(interfaces) under build directory `(build/generated-sources/thrift/<package name>/<class>)` but under my `src/main/java`  I have my classes which has the same package definition as in the generated java files and my classes also implements the interfaces generated by the thrift so how can I configure this in my **build.gradle** so it works on i**ntelliJ** as well as the build

```
plugins {
  id "org.jruyi.thrift" version "0.3.1"
}
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'maven'
apply plugin: "org.jruyi.thrift"

group 'com.hello'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = 1.5

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile group: 'org.apache.thrift', name: 'libthrift', version:'0.9.3'
    compile 'com.datastax.cassandra:cassandra-driver-core:3.0.0'
    compile 'com.datastax.cassandra:cassandra-driver-mapping:3.0.0'
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
}

compileThrift {
    thriftExecutable "/usr/local/hello/bin/thrift"
    sourceDir "src/main/thrift"
    createGenFolder false
}

task thrift(type: Exec) {
    commandLine '/usr/local/hello/bin/thrift'
}


compileJava {
    dependsOn 'compileThrift'
```

Comment: Does thrift generate those sources via gradle?

Comment: yes. I attached my gradle file

Comment: How about: `sourceSets.main.java { srcDir "$buildDir/generated-sources/thrift" }`

Comment: Who is this [doppleganger?!?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35232344/gradle-thrift-plugin-by-example) Seriously, what are the odds that these 2 questions would be asked on the same exact day...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The gradle build should work automatically.
To make it work on Intellij, try adding the following to your build.gradle.

```
idea.module.sourceDirs += file("$buildDir/generated-sources/thrift")
```

Don't forget to refresh your gradle projects.