# Gradle Thrift Plugin by Example

Tags: groovy, gradle, thrift

**Please note:** Although this question specifically calls out the [Gradle Thrift plugin](https://github.com/jruyi/thrift-gradle-plugin), I *believe* this is just a general Gradle question that any battle-weary Gradle veteran could help me with.

---

I am new to [Apache Thrift](https://thrift.apache.org) and only quasi-familiar with Gradle (2.4.x). I am trying to get the Gradle Thrift plugin to work and am encountering a few issues that are likely just gaps in my Gradle knowledge.

Here is my sample project: [thrifty](https://github.com/hotmeatballsoup/thrifty)

If you clone it and run `./gradlew compileThrift`, you'll see it does exactly what the Gradle Thrift README says it will do. It generates source under `build/generated-sources/thrift/*`.

I would like to compile and build this source. For the Java source that it generates, I'd like to produce a JAR library...**so what's the best way to do this?** Should I copy, say, `build/generated-sources/thrift/gen-java/*` to `src/main/java`, and then run `build`?

Comment: Interesting that this question should appear twice today. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35213894/how-can-i-add-a-generated-source-folder-to-my-source-path-in-gradle-and-intellij#comment58145830_35213894

Comment: @RaGe hmmm...  wish i'd seen that before answering...

Comment: @RaGe...that is definitely crazy weird. I will attest that I am **not** that user, but seem to have an evil twin out there attempting to solve the same problems I am (or perhaps I am the evil twin, mua ha ha)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

so, you should just be able to add the following to your build script

```
compileThrift {
    outputDir = file('src/generated/thrift')
}

sourceSets {
    main.java.srcDirs += 'src/generated/thrift/gen-java'
}
```

so the thrift plugin will generate into a folder under src (I just prefer this, to source code being in build)

and then you can add these sources to the directories the java plugin checks

no idea about your extra python question